# Why does a closure introduce a borrow when the same code inlined does not?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

This code works:

```
extern crate num;

use num::{BigInt, FromPrimitive, Zero};

fn sample() {
    let mut to_factor = "600851475143".parse::<BigInt>().unwrap();

    let mut prime = BigInt::from_i32(2).unwrap();

    let zero = BigInt::zero();

    //let is_div = |n, p| { n % p == zero};

    loop {
        if &to_factor % &prime == zero {
            to_factor = &to_factor / &prime;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    println!("{}", to_factor);
}
```

but if I try to replace the condition in the loop with a closure, it doesn't compile anymore:

```
fn sample() {
    let mut to_factor = "600851475143".parse::<BigInt>().unwrap();

    let mut prime = BigInt::from_i32(2).unwrap();

    let zero = BigInt::zero();

    let is_div = |n, p| { n % p == zero};

    loop {
        if is_div(&to_factor, &prime) {
            to_factor = &to_factor / &prime;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    println!("{}", to_factor);
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `to_factor` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:16:13
   |
15 |         if is_div(&to_factor, &prime) {
   |                    --------- borrow of `to_factor` occurs here
16 |             to_factor = &to_factor / &prime;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `to_factor` occurs here
```

It seems fine to me -- the borrow should be "over" by the time we alter `to_factor`, certainly?

To increase the confusion, if I replace `is_div` with an actual function:

```
fn is_div(n: &BigInt, p: &BigInt) -> bool {
    return to_factor % p == BigInt::zero()
}
```

it works fine.

I am a beginner in Rust, but not to programming generally. I'm pretty sure this has to do with ownership, but it might also have to do with how closures are implemented?

These examples are a MWE from the actual code I was trying to write. They're not really meaningful at this point but they demonstrate the same compile error.

Comment: `let is_div = |&n, p| { n % p == zero};` should work. Where is `BigInt` from?

Comment: @Centril num crate

Comment: @saarrrr I tried with `num`, didn't work - perhaps it was an outdated version tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running into a implementation limitation of the Rust type system, specifically with regards to type inference of closure arguments. Namely, the inferred types are subtly different when you declare a closure that isn't immediately used compared to a closure that is immediately used.

This closure works because type inference can immediately connect the parameters to the arguments:

```
loop {
    if (|n, p| n % p == zero)(&to_factor, &prime) {
        to_factor = &to_factor / &prime;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

This also works, as we define the types of the arguments immediately:

```
let is_div = |n: &BigInt, p: &BigInt| n % p == zero;

loop {
    if is_div(&to_factor, &prime) {
        to_factor = &to_factor / &prime;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

This is also the reason that your function version worked.

There are a multitude of issues about this on the issue tracker (it's a very hard thing to search for!), but [12679](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/12679) is an older one.

This is a reason you often see closures defined inline.

Comment: Very helpful -- thanks. I'm still a bit confused about why it was comfortable taking a borrow as an argument when it seems to think it wants the thing itself. In the future I'll use one of these workarounds.

Comment: @RichardRast you'll note that I was cautious to not say what the misbehaving code *is* doing; that's because I don't know for sure! I have some suspicions, but baseless speculation doesn't help anyone ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As you've written it, the `is_div` closure does not borrow `to_factor`, it takes it forever.  If you change the closure signature to borrow `to_factor` it works.

```
let is_div = |&n, p| { n % p == zero};
```

Can't use crates on the playground but this illustrates it.

```
fn main() {
    let mut to_factor = "654684234".parse::<i32>().unwrap();

    let prime = 2;

    let zero = 0;

    let is_div = |&n, p| n % p == zero;

    loop {
        if is_div(&to_factor, &prime) {
            to_factor = &to_factor / &prime;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    println!("{}", to_factor);
}
```

Comment: Can't accept until I understand. I'm passing `&to_factor` to it -- so it shouldn't be able to take it forever! Is it taking the _borrow_ forever? Is this a closure thing? Because it works for functions.

Comment: @RichardRast See edit, hopefully that clears it up for you.  Your function/closure signatures are not the same, that's why it worked in your function and not your closure.

Comment: Still confused. If the signature of the closure was `BigInt`, why was it legal to call it on `&BigInt`? The compiler seems to have no issue with the call itself, only that I modified `to_factor` afterward.

Comment: *change the closure signature to borrow `to_factor`* — that change does not really cause a borrow, it only dereferences the passed-in parameter; `&foo` is a pattern, not a type. *Can't use crates on the playground* — https://play.integer32.com/